# How can I write a file of tuples?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

Im trying to get to write a list of tuples into a file and then organise them in Value and lowest to highest, but I always get the same error. Is there any way this can be done?

Here is my code:

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
class_name = input("Which class are you in? ")
score = 0

class_name = class_name + ".txt"


f = open(class_name, 'w')
for t in class_name:
    line = ' '.join(str(x) for x in t)
    f.write(line + '\n')
f.close()


#See previous scores
print('Please type viewscores() to view the scores')
def viewscores():
    viewscore = input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class? ").lower()
    if viewscore == 'yes':
        viewscore_way = input("a) Alphabetically b)Lowest to highest c)Highest to lowest? ").lower()
    elif viewscore != "yes".lower():
        print ("Press any key to exit")
        ex = input ("")
    if viewscore_way == "a".lower():
        with open(class_name, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
        print(sorted(lines, key=str.lower))
        f.close()
    elif viewscore_way == "b".lower():
        with open(class_name, 'r') as fp:
            lines = [line.strip() for line in fp]
            data = [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in lines]
            sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
            print(sorted_by_second)
        f.close()
    elif viewscore_way == "c".lower():
        print(sorted(data,key=itemgetter(1), reverse = True))
```

But, when I run my code I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    viewscores()
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\list.py", line 40, in viewscores
    sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\list.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    sorted_by_second = sorted(data, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How do I remove the 'out of range error' and get everything to work?

Comment: This piece of code seems to be rather pointless: `f = open(class_name, 'w')
for t in class_name:
    line = ' '.join(str(x) for x in t)
    f.write(line + '\n')
f.close()`

Comment: You are looping through the characters in the filename and then writing each character on a separate line. Where do you actually *write the scores* to the files *properly*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write your data with a space as separator but read it back splitting at a comma.